# Creating vector method

Tags: c++

The line "list listObject;" is saying that char is not allowed and listObject in unidentified. Could someone give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

```
char list;
vector<char> v(20);
list<char> listObject;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    v[i] = 'A' + i;

cout << "Original contents of vector:\n";
for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i] << " ";
cout << "\n\n";

char str[] = "-TEST MESSAGE-";
for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    listObject.push_back(str[i]);

copy(listObject.begin(), listObject.end(), v.begin());

// display result
cout << "Contents of vector after copy:\n";
for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i] << " ";
```

Comment: You define a `char` with name `list` and then try to define an object of type `list`.

Comment: (Unless you take out the `using namespace std;` you obviously have somewhere)

Comment: Where is this vector method you're creating?

Answer (score 0):

The first point, as owacodes has stated, you try to define a local variable called list, which conflicts with the name of the container list.

As a second point: I made a compileable example with some changes you might profit from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v(20); 
    // use iota for the assignment, it does what you want
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 'A');

    std::cout << "Original contents of vector:\n";
    for(auto n: v) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // use a std::string instaed of char[], it is easier to use and less error prone
    std::string str("-TEST MESSAGE-");
    std::list<char> listObject;
    listObject.insert(listObject.begin(),str.begin(),str.end());

    std::copy(listObject.begin(), listObject.end(), v.begin());
    // be careful, v is not resized (str will be truncated with a longer message)

    std::cout << "new contents of vector:\n";
    for(auto n: v) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
Original contents of vector:
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T 
new contents of vector:
- T E S T   M E S S A G E - O P Q R S T
```